# PHP mapiHTTP interface

Tags: php, http, exchange-server, mapi

I'm trying to build a PHP mapiHTTP interface to solve RCA (https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) Exchange Server->Outlook connectivity test. I was able to create a valid ActiveSync  response to start a mapiHTTP session. I implemented a response to a "Bind" request (EcDoConnectEx) according to [MX-OCSRPC] 3.1.4.1.2.1 Server Topology Information. Then RCA responded always with a error message

```
Testing the address book "Check Name" operation for user t1@hvfd.de against server hvfd.de.
An error occurred while attempting to resolve the name.

A protocol layer error occured. MapiHttpResponseCode: 12
Error-LID: 63008
Response code: 12 InvalidPayload
```

The header received on server from RCA:

```
Host: xxx.de
User-Agent: MapiHttpClient
Content-Length: 45
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Client-Request-Id: 127b6931-b891-451b-b279-61c72a0541ca
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-Clientapplication: MapiHttpClient/15.20.5504.0
X-Clientinfo: 1a36f3ef-fb87-46dd-8ffe-c9810e0576a4:1
X-Forwarded-For: 52.109.8.10
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Requestid: 68cfa682-7b93-4147-935a-87dde182c33c:1
X-Requesttype: Bind
Request: POST /mapi/nspi/?mailboxId=dDFAaHZmZC5kZQ== HTTP/1.1
```

Body:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 | FF 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
00000014  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 E4 04 00 | 00 09 04 00 | 00 09 04 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
00000028  00 00 00 00 | 00          |             |             |             |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤
```

Pseudo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<syncgw>
  <Flags Typ="I4">0</Flags>
  <HasState Typ="B">255</HasState>
  <State>
    <SortType Typ="I4">0</SortType>
    <ContainerID Typ="I4">0</ContainerID>
    <CurrentRec: Typ="I4">0</CurrentRec:>
    <Delta Typ="I4">0</Delta>
    <NumPos Typ="I4">0</NumPos>
    <TotalRecs Typ="I4">0</TotalRecs>
    <CodePage Typ="I4">1252</CodePage>
    <TemplateLocale Typ="I4">1033</TemplateLocale>
    <SortLocale Typ="I4">1033</SortLocale>
  </State>
  <AuxiliaryBufferSize Typ="I4">0</AuxiliaryBufferSize>
  <AuxiliaryBuffer Typ="V"/>
</syncgw>
```

My server is sending back:

```
X-Requesttype: Bind
Set-Cookie: session_context=6334182282e4e;request_sequence=1
X-ClientInfo: 1a36f3ef-fb87-46dd-8ffe-c9810e0576a4:1
X-ServerApplication: Exchange/15.0.466.0
X-ExpirationInfo: 100000
X-ResponseCode: 0
X-ElapsedTime: 200
X-StartTime: Wed, 28 Sep 22 09:47:14 +0000
Content-Type: application/mapi-http
Content-Length: 244
```

and Body:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 73 79 6E 63 | 2A 67 77 20 | 73 65 72 76 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | sync | *gw. | serv | 
00000014  65 72 00 00 | D0 00 00 00 | 00 00 04 00 | D0 00 D0 00 | 0C 00 01 0A |   er¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤. | 
00000028  00 00 00 00 | A0 86 01 00 | A0 00 01 16 | 98 00 00 00 | 0A 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | .¤¤¤ | 
0000003C  00 00 00 00 | F0 55 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤U¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
00000050  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
00000064  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
00000078  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
0000008C  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
000000A0  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
000000B4  00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | 
000000C8  00 00 00 00 | 30 00 00 00 | 08 00 01 17 | 02 00 00 00 | 06 00 01 4B |   ¤¤¤¤ | 0¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤K | 
000000DC  00 00 0E 00 | 01 4E 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 08 00 01 46 |   ¤¤¤¤ | ¤N¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤¤ | ¤¤¤F | 
000000F0  00 00 00 00 |             |             |             |             |   ¤¤¤¤ |
```

Pseudo code:

```
<syncgw>
  <!-- This is converted binary data send to client -->
  <Status Typ="I4">0</Status>
  <ErrCode Typ="I4">0</ErrCode>
  <GUID Typ="S16">sync*gw server</GUID>
  <AuxiliaryBufferSize Typ="I4">208</AuxiliaryBufferSize>
  <AuxiliaryBuffer>
    <RPC_HEADER_EXT>
      <Version Typ="I2">0</Version>
      <Flags Typ="I2">4</Flags>
      <Size Typ="I2">208</Size>
      <ActualSize Typ="I2">208</ActualSize>
      <AUX_HEADER>
        <Size Typ="I2">12</Size>
        <Version Typ="I1">1</Version>
        <Type Typ="I1">10</Type>
        <AUX_CLIENT_CONTROL>
          <EnableFlags Typ="I4">0</EnableFlags>
          <ExpiryTime Typ="I4">100000</ExpiryTime>
        </AUX_CLIENT_CONTROL>
      </AUX_HEADER>
      <AUX_HEADER>
        <Size Typ="I2">160</Size>
        <Version Typ="I1">1</Version>
        <Type Typ="I1">22</Type>
        <AUX_OSVERSIONINFO>
          <OSVersionInfoSize Typ="I4">152</OSVersionInfoSize>
          <MajorVersion Typ="I4">10</MajorVersion>
          <MinorVersion Typ="I4">0</MinorVersion>
          <BuildNumber Typ="I4">22000</BuildNumber>
          <Reserved1 Typ="S132"/>
          <ServicePackMajor Typ="I2">0</ServicePackMajor>
          <ServicePackMinor Typ="I2">0</ServicePackMinor>
          <Reserved2 Typ="S4">0</Reserved2>
        </AUX_OSVERSIONINFO>
      </AUX_HEADER>
      <AUX_HEADER>
        <Size Typ="I2">8</Size>
        <Version Typ="I1">1</Version>
        <Type Typ="I1">23</Type>
        <AUX_EXORGINFO>
          <OrgFlags Typ="I4">2</OrgFlags>
        </AUX_EXORGINFO>
      </AUX_HEADER>
      <AUX_HEADER>
        <Size Typ="I2">6</Size>
        <Version Typ="I1">1</Version>
        <Type Typ="I1">75</Type>
        <SERVER_SESSION_INFO>
          <OffsetServerSessionContextInfo Typ="I2">0</OffsetServerSessionContextInfo>
        </SERVER_SESSION_INFO>
      </AUX_HEADER>
      <AUX_HEADER>
        <Size Typ="I2">14</Size>
        <Version Typ="I1">1</Version>
        <Type Typ="I1">78</Type>
        <PROTOCOL_DEVICE_IDENTIFICATION>
          <DeviceManufacturerOffset Typ="I2">0</DeviceManufacturerOffset>
          <DeviceModelOffset Typ="I2">0</DeviceModelOffset>
          <DeviceSerialNumberOffset Typ="I2">0</DeviceSerialNumberOffset>
          <DeviceVersionOffset Typ="I2">0</DeviceVersionOffset>
          <DeviceFirmwareVersionOffset Typ="I2">0</DeviceFirmwareVersionOffset>
        </PROTOCOL_DEVICE_IDENTIFICATION>
      </AUX_HEADER>
      <AUX_HEADER>
        <Size Typ="I2">8</Size>
        <Version Typ="I1">1</Version>
        <Type Typ="I1">70</Type>
        <SERVER_CAPABILITIES>
          <ServerCapabilityFlags Typ="I4">0</ServerCapabilityFlags>
        </SERVER_CAPABILITIES>
      </AUX_HEADER>
    </RPC_HEADER_EXT>
  </AuxiliaryBuffer>
</syncgw>
```

Any help appreciated!